# Disabling Magento_CatalogStaging creates a staging duplicate query issue for a record that doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database

I am attempting to disable Catalog Staging without starting over.
I ran this command

```
bin/magento mo:d Magento_CatalogStaging Magento_CatalogImportExportStaging Magento_BundleStaging Magento_ConfigurableProductStaging Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteStaging Magento_DownloadableStaging Magento_WeeeStaging Magento_CatalogInventoryStaging
```

However, it creates this query error below which doesn't seem to make sense because the value '0-79-0' means that the first 0 should reference an entity_id but I do not have a row_id or entity_id with the value of 0(obviously).

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-79-0' for key
'CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID', query was:
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime` 
ADD COLUMN `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  
COMMENT "Entity ID", 
DROP COLUMN `row_id`, 
DROP KEY `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_ROW_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID`, 
ADD CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` 
FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) 
REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE, 
ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` 
UNIQUE KEY (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`)
```

I have tried to run a query checking for any duplicates in general but I am not getting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the attributes were already created on this instance, so  attribute 79 represented special_from_date which is not supposed to be in commerce because you are supposed to manage the attributes through staging not using attribute dates to set when a product is new or special. I went and deleted the individual attributes.